# Windows Firewall Logs, поле Size везде 0

Tags: windows, windows-server

Всем привет.

Появилась необходимость смотреть по логам Windows Firewall проходящий трафик. Все легко включилось, события пишутся, но главное поле SIZE, которое указывает количество байт везде равно 0. На сервере работает свыше 10 человек, постоянно загружая и выгружая с него файлы. Можно как то заставить туда писать размер?

Расположение самого лога
[image: Расположение самого лога]

Содержимое логов с нулевым полем
[image: Содержимое логов с нулевым полем]

Я нашел тред с такой же проблемой вот здесь
[Size = 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/88068/packet-size-of-windows-firewall-log-is-zero.html)

Но ответ на проблему не был дан.